# Struts2 - Different browsers, different machines, same form data

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I believe it has something to do with Struts2 `ValueStack`, but if you guys could give me a hand with that would be great.

I have the following setup: Spring 3 + Struts 2.
My struts actions are pretty much like this:

```
@ParentPackage("struts-default")
public class StepOneAction extends ActionSupport {
...
}
```

Such `Action` has a method that is my forward:

```
@Action(value = "/bla", results = { @Result(name = "ble", location = "/bli.jsp") })
public String populate() {
    ...
    return BLE;
}
```

Finally such `Action` is @Autowired.

What's puzzling me is that if I open, say Firefox, navigate to the first page - it's a 3 step wizard - fill the form and submit **THEN** open another browser, say Opera, and navigate to the first page, Opera has the data populated from Firefox.

***How's that possible? What am I missing?***

Comment: Hi Steven, I think it actually was that. I was creating my actions as singleton beans - which is the default scope. After changing to request it fixed itself up. Thanx!

Comment: Glad to hear that resolved it. I moved my comment down to an answer so that it can stand out a bit more in case someone else runs into this issue. Feel free to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ValueStack is per-request, so I don't see how it could possibly be a factor here.

It sounds like Spring is treating `StepOneAction` as a singleton, which would account for the behavior you are seeing. Actions need to be instantiated per-request.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you haven't defined a member on the JSP page or Servlet that keep the same value among multiple sessions